# PHP Datatable server-side processing counter column

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm trying to make a counter for my datatables but every time i click on the next page, I will get the previous page data.

Anyone got a solution for this? Here's my JS:

```
var pTable = $('#users-table').DataTable({

        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        bFilter: false,
        ajax: {
            url: '{!! route('datatables.filter') !!}',
            data: function(d){ //these data will be passed to filter
                d.username = $('input[name=username]').val();
                d.email = $('input[name=email]').val();
                d.status = $('input[name=status]').val();
            }
        },
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "searchable": false,
            "orderable": false,
            "targets": 0
        } ],
        order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
        columns: [
            { data: null},
            { data: 'username', name: 'username' },
            { data: 'email', name: 'email' },
            { data: 'user_id', name: 'user_id' , 'visible': false},
        ],

    });

    pTable.on('order.dt search.dt page.dt', function () {
        var start = pTable.page.info().start;
        var info = pTable.page.info();
        pTable.column(0, {order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
            cell.innerHTML = start+i+1;
        } );
    } ).draw();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your page.dt change to draw.dt

Comment: page.dt wont work because the table would be drawn before the code is loaded while draw.dt inits after drawing.